# Azure SQL databases- CPU vs Cost

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, azure-sql-database

Can any one Help me out with differences in azure databases computational Power and cost, I need to scale up my database which one is better approach ?

Like What is the difference if i take two S3 databases or one P1 database?
two S3 tier database will be (100x2)DTU/(~$150.00/mo x 2) or one P1 tier database will be 125 DTU/$465.00/mo i.e

I am Currently using one S3 database with my web application on azure. My operations are so intensive that it sometimes consumes Full 100% DTU for 10-20 mins making things slower for other users or sometimes may also cause deadlocks. Current size of Db is 60GB and almost fully indexed.

Answer (score 1):

The first question is if it's even possible to easily partition your data so that you can split between two or more S3 tiers. If you cannot easily partition your data, then there's no use thinking about going to two or more S3's to save money.

Microsoft hasn't told us the exact formula for a DTU, but we know it's a combination of CPU and IO. The smallest Premium tier instance gives you ten times the IO of an S3.

For more details on the differences between the tiers, [go here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-service-tiers).

Comment: so you are saying that 1 x P1 > 2 x S3 in CPU and IO ?

Comment: Yes. Per the link above, "The Premium tier offers more CPU and starts at 10x more IO compared to the highest performance level in the Standard tier." That means that the IO is 10x greater, but we do not have a definitive measure of how much more CPU there is between the S3 and P1, other than "more".

Answer (score 0):

With a Premium server you have SSD storage available for the server. You can also use in-memory OLTP that can greatly improve performance.

If your database operation is known for using multiple cores for an extended time then forget about using Standard tier and choose Premium tiers.

Hope this helps.